# Zeppelin and BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, apache-zeppelin

I'm looking for a visualisation and analytical notebook engine for `BigQuery` and am interested in `Apache`/`Zeppelin`.

We have internal capability in `Python` and `R` and want to use this with our `BigQuery` back end.

All the installation scenarios I've seen so far ( eg: https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/09/analyzing-bigquery-datasets-using-bigquery-interpreter-for-apache-zeppelin) seem to require the installation of a fairly hefty `Scala`/`Spark` cluster which I don't see the need for (and which would cost a lot)

Is it possible to install `Zeppelin` without the cluster in `Google Cloud`?

Comment: Yes. Zeppelin is just a java application. Just download the binary, unzip it and started by `bin/zeppelin-demon.sh start`. And from 0.6.1 it's support BigQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with 0.6.1 there is a [Native BigQuery Interpreter for Apache Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.1/interpreter/bigquery.html) available.
It allows you to process and analyze datasets stored in Google BigQuery by directly running SQL against it from within an Apache Zeppelin notebook.
So you do not need anymore query BigQuery using Apache Spark as it was only way before